# Sort array based on key value

Tags: php

I'm using a form where the pair of inputs can be added per automatic. One store value in `select` and the other as `input`

After submit I receive the values in `array` and I need to associate them together. So all `key` values `[0]` belongs together and all `[1]` and so on.

```
Array
(
[issue] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 3
    )

[qty] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )
)
```

How can I do this using PHP?

Comment: you want to sort array on the base of main key or sub key ? write down image code that what output you want

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple foreach loop.

```
$combined = array();
foreach ($_POST["issue"] as $k=>$v) {
  $combined[$k] = array($_POST["issue"][$k], $_POST["qty"][$k]);
}
print_r($combined);
```